# R: Pearson correlation rcorr(x,y) [x=matrix, y=vector] ignores y

Tags: r, correlation

I have a matrix `x` (30x2000) of 2000 gene expressions in different cell lines and a vector `y` (30x1) of a continuous variable outcome. I want to calculate Pearson correlation between each gene and the outcome, so, I expect a 2000x1 vector of r-values. I've used `rcorr(x,y)` but the result is a 2000x2000 matrix, so I guess it's ignoring the `y` and calculating all genes against all (the manual says:

> x = a numeric matrix with at least 5 rows and at least 2 columns (if y is absent)

But can I have more than one column and have `y` too? Do I have to use a different function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `apply` the `cor` function across the columns of your `x` matrix...

```
apply( x , 2 , cor , y = y )
```

#### A reproducible example

```
#  For reproducible data
set.seed(1)

#  3 x 4 matrix
x <- matrix( runif(12) , nrow = 3 )
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] 0.2655087 0.9082078 0.9446753 0.06178627
#[2,] 0.3721239 0.2016819 0.6607978 0.20597457
#[3,] 0.5728534 0.8983897 0.6291140 0.17655675

# Length 3 vector
y <- runif(3)
#[1] 0.6870228 0.3841037 0.7698414

# Length 4 otuput vector
apply( x , 2 , cor , y = y )
#[1]  0.3712437  0.9764443  0.2249998 -0.4903723
```

Comment: You don't need to use `apply` here.  Just `cor(x,y)` will do, or if you want it as a vector rather than a matrix `array(cor(x,y))`

Comment: @mrip you are absolutely right. Why don't you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 8):

Using the function `cor` will work.  In general, if `x` is MxN andy `y` is MxP, then `cor(x,y)` will be an NxP matrix where the entry (i,j) is the correlation between `x[,i]` and `y[,j]`.

Building on SimonO101's reproducible example:

```
> set.seed(1)
> x <- matrix( runif(12) , nrow = 3 )
> y <- runif(3)
> cor(x,y)
           [,1]
[1,]  0.3712437
[2,]  0.9764443
[3,]  0.2249998
[4,] -0.4903723
```

If you want just a vector and not a matrix:

```
> array(cor(x,y))
[1]  0.3712437  0.9764443  0.2249998 -0.4903723
```

Comment: Thanks @mrip, @SimonO101. `rcorr` returns 3 matrices (r, n, p). Can `rcorr` by adapted using `apply` so that you can get the p-values vector too? or some option of `cor` that does the same?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `rcorr`, but it sounds like something along the lines of `apply(x,2,function(a,b){rcorr(a,b)$p},y)` should give you the `p` matrix.